# How to use location.path with angularjs rather than $http.get

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, joomla3.0, joomla-component

Hi I am working on a angularjs app. This is actually embedded in to joomla.

The URL that caters the json responses keeps changing based on the menu item clicked. For example:

```
http://localhost/testsite/index.php/good?format=raw
http://localhost/testsite/index.php/bad?format=raw
http://localhost/testsite/index.php/ugly?format=raw
```

Is there a way I can use location.path instead of hardcoding a URL.

My controller is below:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
app.controller('customersCrtl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $http.get('http://localhost/testsite/index.php/good?format=raw').success(function(data){
        $scope.list = data[0]; //before the code was $scope.list = data; The second response with [[that doesn't work is an array with an array inside of it.
        $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
        $scope.entryLimit = 10; //max no of items to display in a page
        $scope.filteredItems = $scope.list.length; //Initially for no filter  
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;
    });
    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
    };
    $scope.filter = function() {
        $timeout(function() { 
            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
        }, 10);
    };
    $scope.sort_by = function(predicate) {
        $scope.predicate = predicate;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did resolve this issue by using the

```
window.location.pathname+"\?format=raw"
```

Basically In joomla, i have created multiple menu items for a same component.

for example to display all the hotels in london . I create a menu item from component and select london. This component generates a json message but in order to use this with angularjs i have to provide the url for the json so angular controller can get json.

So in this case the url has to be http://test.com/london?format=raw.

But to have multiple menu items i will have to create multiple angular controllers for each city which beats the point of component and only one controller.

so I used window.location.pathname+"\?format=raw" in the http.get of angularjs and this did resolve the issue.

i am not sure if there are any better ways of doing it but am open for suggestions.

hope this resolves the issues for some one else.

Regards,
Jai